# Not able to set the left, top position on hover, placement is not related to parent element

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular8

In my directive, on `mouseenter` I am trying to place a element with absolute values. for that I am getting the value of the host listener.

but when i try to implement, I am not getting the dynamic element properly placed with it's parent. getting placed in wrong location.

any one help me to understand here?

here is my directive ts file :

```
import { Directive, Renderer2, HostListener, Input, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[iboToolTip]'
})
export class ToolTipDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() iboToolTip: string;

    container: HTMLElement;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2 ) { }

    ngOnInit() {


        this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'ibo-tooltip-holder');

    }

    @HostListener('mouseenter') mouseover($event) {

        const parentPosition = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

        this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, this.getToolTip(parentPosition)); //getting value
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave($event) {

        this.renderer.removeChild(document.body, this.container);

    }

    getToolTip(parentPosition) {

        const lefPos = parentPosition.left; //getting left
        const topPos = parentPosition.top; //getting top

        this.container = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        this.container.style.top =  topPos + 'px'; //setting value
        this.container.style.left = lefPos + 'px'; //setting value
        this.container.setAttribute('class', 'ibo-tooltip');
        this.container.innerHTML = `<div>I am here!!</div>`;
        return this.container;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated the getTooltip with window scroll property, it works fine now.

```
getToolTip(parentPosition) {

        const buffer = 20;
        const lefPos = parentPosition.left;
        const topPos = parentPosition.top;

        const windowTop = window.scrollY + buffer;
        const windowLeft = window.scrollX;

        this.container = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        this.container.style.top = (windowTop + topPos) + 'px';
        this.container.style.left = lefPos + 'px';
        this.container.setAttribute('class', 'ibo-tooltip');
        this.container.innerHTML = `<div>I am here!!</div>`;

        console.log('this.container', this.container);
        return this.container;

    }
```